# how to check each subdirectory has a unique name in a directory

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have a folder where subdirectories and files exist. I want to ensure no two directories have same name. How can do this?

Comment: You can't create two sub-directories with the same name. The second attempt will fail with an error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command will print the directory names that appear multiple times:

```
find path/to/dir -type d -printf "%f\n" | sort | uniq -d
```

If the output is empty, then there are no duplicate names.
If the output is not empty, you could find the complete path of the duplicates with:

```
find path/to/dir -type d -name the-name
```

Warning: due to using `\n` as the delimiter of file names in the `-printf` option, this will not work if you have some directories with `\n` embedded in them. Hopefully that's an acceptable limitation.

The `-printf` option of `find` is available in GNU implementations, common on Linux systems, and may not be available in BSD implementations, common on BSD systems.
If your `find` doesn't have that option, then you can use this instead:

```
find path/to/dir -type d | awk -F/ '{ print $NF }' | sort | uniq -d
```

Comment: this has some error. like find: -printf: unknown primary or operator. I change it to the print but I still got error like that find: %f\n: unknown primary or operator.

Comment: @neouyghur the `-printf` option is specific to the GNU implementation, and I haven't seen a Linux that didn't have it. Your question is tagged Linux. Are you trying to run this in a different OS? (Mac OS X?) I can rewrite to work without that too, one sec.

Comment: actually it is for linux, but I am testing it with my mac. Could you offer the mac version too.

Comment: @neouyghur there you go